# ASP.NET code snippit to query database for unique field value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create custom remote data annotation to check for unique values.

So far I have:

```
[Remote("checkForUniqueSpeciesName", "Create", ErrorMessage = "A Species by that name already exists.")]
public string SpeciesName { get; set; }
```

and

```
public ActionResult checkForUniqueSpeciesName(string species_name)
    {
        bool is_unique = ........
        return Json(is_unique, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

To be honest, I don't really understand how this works, I'm just trying to follow examples found on the web. I guess `checkForUniqueSpeciesName` is called when the form is submitted, and the method returns true or false. Is there something I need to put in the view to make the validation message come up, such as?

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpeciesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Do I need that?

Model Species.cs:
    public class Species
    {
        [Key]
        public int SpeciesId { get; set; }

```
    [Display(Name = "Species")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a species name.")]
    [Remote("CheckForUniqueSpeciesName", "Create", ErrorMessage = "A Species by that name already exists.")]
    public string SpeciesName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller SpeciesController.cs:

namespace Gators3.Controllers
{
    public class SpeciesController : Controller
    {
        private GatorsContext db = new GatorsContext();

```
    // GET: Species
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Species.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Species/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SpeciesId,SpeciesName")] Species species)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Species.Add(species);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(species);
    }

    public ActionResult CheckForUniqueSpeciesName(string speciesName)
    {
        using (GatorsContext ctx = new GatorsContext())
        {
            bool isUnique = !ctx.Species.Any(s => s.SpeciesName == speciesName);
            return Json(isUnique, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
.
.
.
.
```

View Views->Species->Create.cshtml:

```
@model Gators3.Models.Species

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Species</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpeciesName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpeciesName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpeciesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better stop following examples you don't understand, and learn to understand them instead.

Comment: Yes you need `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in order to display the message (but it needs to be `m => m.species_name` - i.e. to match the property name and controller parameter name - or if the property is `SpeciesId`, then the method parameter need to be `SpeciesId`). And your method is not called when the form is submitted - its called beforehand, and if the method returns `false` the form is not submitted until the error is corrected

Comment: @StephenMuecke -- yup, I mean `SpeciesName`, I did a cut and paste. Thanks for clearing that up about when the validation runs. Any thoughts about what to put in the "..."?

Comment: Without seeing more code, impossible to tell, but it might be something like `bool is_unique = !db.Species.Any(s => s.SpeciesName == SpeciesName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess checkForUniqueSpeciesName is called when the form is
>   submitted, and the method returns true or false.

No, that is not the case. The `[RemoteAttribute]` adds some JavaScript to your page automatically that will call a method on your Controller to do some server side validation and display the result on the page without the user needing to submit the whole HTML form. i.e. The validation is invoked when you tab out of the text box, not when you click submit.

With your code, I assume your controller is named `CreateController`?

I'm guessing you're just missing your data access code to actually check uniqueness?

So something like this would be required:

```
public ActionResult CheckForUniqueSpeciesName(string speciesName)
{
    using (YourEntityFrameworkDbContext ctx = new YourEntityFrameworkDbContext())
    {
        bool isUnique = !ctx.Species.Any(s => s.SpeciesName == speciesName);
        return Json(isUnique , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, you just need something like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SpeciesName)
```

Which will display the validation message you specified in your `[Remote]` attribute.

By the way, just as a side note - the coding conventions/casing you've applied to some of your code won't be popular with most C# programmers (unless your team are abiding by an unusual standard) so note the formatting I've applied.

**Update** - I think your code needs to have the following:

```
[Remote("CheckForUniqueSpeciesName", "Species", ErrorMessage="A Species by that name already exists.")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanations! Obviously I'm just starting out. The controller is `SpeciesController`, and has a `Create` method. Pretty much what scaffolding built for me. So, I put your code in the controller (except I had to change `s=s.SpeciesName` to `s=>s.SpeciesName`) keeping your coding conventions (which I should learn to adhere to). I made sure that the method name matches in the `Remote` annotation. What happens is that when I click submit in the create page, nothing happens, regardless of whether the species name is unique or not. I'll add some more code.

Comment: The remote validation should occur when you leave the species text box, not when you submit the form. I think your problem is your arguments in the `[Remote]` declaration. I've updated the answer with what I think it should be.

Comment: That did it. I was confused between using the controller and the controller action method. So many of the examples I was looking at were for username or email, and those have special ways of checking for uniqueness.